# Brwse Server button and UPload Button does not shown

Tags: ckfinder

I have downloaded ckeditor 4 from ckeditor official website. The example of the official website has provided browse server and upload button in image feature. But I does not have these features. Please help me to solve it.

I have try this before but it does not work.

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_dialog_add_file_browser.html#adding-the-browse-server-button

Answer (score 0):

The demo on the [official website](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/demo/) uses [CKFinder](https://ckeditor.com/ckfinder/). This is an adavanced file manager which besides uploading alows you to organize and manage you files. Another advantage is that it takes care of many security aspects connected with uploading, accessing and managing files on server. That software requires a commercial license unfortunately.

If you don't want to use it you can search for other file managers or [simple uploaders](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addons/search/plugins/file%20upload). You can also try creating your own custom uploader - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_browser_api.html.